# Why isnt there a create launcher on desktop right click?

Tags: nautilus, launcher

As the title says, I like unity and its new look. But why isnt there a choice to create a launcher on the desktop by right clicking?

I am currently using XFCE desktop instead just because of this. To much hassle to create launchers or links to websites with unity.

Also it probably wouldnt hurt to have some templates for creating new files. such as text files and picture files etc.

EDIT: yes i wonder why it was removed, why did the developers remove it? what reasons?

Comment: @Alex Questions about design decisions are [not *categorically* off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3075/are-questions-about-design-decisions-considered-constructive). However, this seems like it is a feature request. Kristoffer, if that is the case, it should instead be filed as a bug on Launchpad (but make sure to [read this carefully first](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)), or posted as an idea on [Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) (or both, so long as you make them link to each other).

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to *discuss* this issue, you should use [a forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/). If you are **really asking about why the developers made that decision**, please let us know. Otherwise, this question will likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I want to reopen, as I have changed the name of the question because I think the intention was not to ask theoretically **why** that feature is not there (design decision topic) but **how** to add that option. - Also, I want to add an answer to **that "HOW"** question:  add  right-click Nautilus option *Create launcher here*.

Comment: @cipricus: I think the wording of the question before your change made it abundantly clear that OP was looking for a reason and not a solution. Please try to preserve the spirits of the posts that you edit. For now I rolled back your edit. If you want to discuss this please open a question on Meta. If you want an answer to your somewhat different question please open a regular new question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - I think you are right, and it is much simpler to create a new question, even one non ubuntu-specific: [Add 'Create launcher' to Nautilus context menu (without `gnome-desktop-item-edit`)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/353580/32012).

Answer (score 1):

As to *why* that is a question for the developers, as some of the comments above say.  If you want to edit your question to ask for an easy way to make a launcher, it will likely not be closed as off-topic.

If you *are* just looking for an easier way to make a launcher, I will include it here...

You can get an easier way to make launchers with [**alacarte**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/) it does not include the right click feature but is easier than creating them by hand.

Alacarte requires that Gnome Fallback be installed as a dependency, which have several other dependencies,  it will need a total 35MB of disk space so it may not be an option if you need to conserve disk space.

After installation, if you don't want the selection of **Gnome Classic/Gnome Classic(no effects)** as a possible DE's you can delete `**gnome-session-fallback**` with the Software Center or apt-get.  (there are other ways to get the required dependencies  than allowing Gnome Fallback to be installed but this is the easiest)