# Which Gnome environment is going to appear in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm confused as to which Gnome environment is going to be in 18.04.

As far as I can tell, there is `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and `gnome-shell`. Interesting enough, `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` also installs `gnome-shell`. And, if not to confuse things more, in the past we've had Gnome Flashback (gnome-session-flashback), and Gnome Classic (gnome-session-fallback).

I've installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` on Ubuntu 17.04, and if I hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, it switches to `gnome-shell`. Also, at the login prompt, I can select to go directly to either one.

Can somebody simplify this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is a meta package that installs GNOME Shell, Ubuntu-specific settings, and any other packages that the Ubuntu GNOME team feel should be on a default install. That is what we will be seeing in 18.04's Ubuntu (and there will not be a separate Ubuntu GNOME flavour). From the [release announcement of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/):

> As announced last week by Ubuntu founder Mark Shuttleworth, Ubuntu
>   18.04 LTS will include GNOME instead of Unity. Specifically, it will be GNOME (including gnome-shell) with minimal Ubuntu customization.
>   Next year, if you are using either Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu GNOME
>   16.04 LTS, you will be prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. For normal release users, this upgrade should happen with the release of
>   17.10.
>
> As a result of this decision there will no longer be a separate GNOME
>   flavor of Ubuntu. The development teams from both Ubuntu GNOME and
>   Ubuntu Desktop will be merging resources and focusing on a single
>   combined release, that provides the best of both GNOME and Ubuntu. We
>   are currently liaising with the Canonical teams on how this will work
>   out and more details will be announced in due course as we work out
>   the specifics.

[GNOME Flashback (originally called GNOME Fallback)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback) is still available and will continue to be available. However, it is not the main desktop shell from GNOME, GNOME Shell is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @muru. With the ubuntu-gnome-desktop user experience is so different from the gnome-shell user experience, which are we expected to use on a daily basis, and why include two different user experiences? Does that question make any sense to you? Still a little confused :-)

Comment: What's so different about it? Aside from some light artwork changes, I feel Ubuntu GNOME's GNOME Shell is pretty much the same as GNOME Shell as released by GNOME. It's even in [the FAQ](https://ubuntugnome.org/documentation/faq/): "**Why don’t you customize GNOME more?** Customizing GNOME would take away from our goal of providing GNOME the way GNOME developers intended."

Comment: Maybe I'm just seeing something different than intended. I forget what it says at the login prompt, but if I choose one, it brings me to a menu-driven user interface with no launcher. If I hit the super key, which brings up gnome shell (I believe) it displays a black top panel with a clock in the middle, and a launcher on the left side of the screen. If I hit the super key again, I get brought back to the menu-driven system with no launcher. Is that they way it'll work in 18.04? I guess that I'll just have to play with it some more.

Comment: That sounds like normal GNOME Shell to me. Maybe you'll find another answer by me somewhat useful: https://askubuntu.com/a/617189/158442